# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/jboss/logging/Logger.debug

Tags: java, websphere

While my application is being deployed to websphere 9 i get this error

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org/jboss/logging/Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V (loaded from
>   file:/C:/server/IBM/WebSphere90/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.cdi.logging.jar

It seems that the above jar is being loaded before jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar used by hibernate.
At the same time i have a different machine on which this issue is not present.
`com.ibm.ws.cdi.logging.jar` is missing from the path and the error no longer occurs.
How to fix the error and why in one installation the `cdi.logging.jar` is present and in the not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `com.ibm.ws.cdi.logging.jar` you must be on Websphere 9.0.0.0, I would suggest upgrading to Websphere 9.0.0.5 or later, your issue should be resolved by [PI79787](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI79787).

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

You could add jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar as an isolated shared library and associate it with your application. That will cause it to be preferred over anything provided by the application server.

Comment: how come that in two separate installation in one the cdi logging is there and in another not?

Comment: Are the two installations on different versions? That jar only exists on websphere 9.0.0.0